# Python Multiprocessing pool is freezing at one computer as it is working at another?

Tags: python, numpy, multiprocessing, python-multiprocessing

I developed a multiprocessing python script with `Pool` and `map` functions. It uses Numpy. Interestingly, it freezes even with a single process Pool in my computer (on the dot product of two `[20000, 36]` dim matrices, of course one is transposed ) and it works on my remote server without any flaw. However, the code can run in my computer as well if it is sequential (with out Map function).

Server has very large memory compared to my computer. I thought the problem was memory and try single process pool only and it freezed again. In addition as I observe from system monitor, memory indicator did not overflow. Even the single process pool freezes. If I run the same function without pool and sequentially, it works without problem.

Any idea on how to trace the problem or what might be the reason?

My PC has python 2.7.6 and server has 2.7.5. If there is a known bug, please direct me.
Both machines are on Ubuntu.

Comment: Have you tried on other PCs?

Comment: Seeing the code would help. Can you post the parts of the code that launch/join your subprocesses, the functions your pools are executing, and any shared or global objects?

Comment: problem was memory overflow.